# Duplicate all outgoing IP packets

Tags: networking, linux-networking

We're having an issue with our ISP where 75% of our outgoing IP packets are lost to the ether. Incoming packets are totally unaffected, and we assume we're not being throttled because we can send massive bursts of UDP packets without seeing an increase in the dropped packet ratio.

The ISP has been exceptionally slow (weeks) in fixing the issue, and we need to implement a workaround on our end until they can fix the issue. One solution that seems promising would be to duplicate all outgoing IP packets. I realize this might not be ideal for a host of reasons, but we'd still like to give a try.

Is it possible to duplicate all outgoing IP packets and if so, how?

We're mainly using Ubuntu Server 20.04 LTS, but also have some Windows 10 Pro desktops.

Comment: take a lawyer and screw the isp.

Comment: I dont see this as a viable solution. On the receiving end there is no mechanism for discarding duplicate packets that do get through. I would escalate the problem with the isp. Your business is essentially "down" with this kind of issue.

Comment: Or get an offer from another ISP if this one can't do their job properly.

Comment: Who told you this is a "solution"? It seems to be missing some important steps.

Comment: @Greg Askew "One solution that seems promising would be to duplicate all outgoing IP packets. "

Comment: "I realize this might not be ideal for a host of reasons, but we'd still like to give a try."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`iptables -j TEE` target is designed exactly to clone matched packets:

[`man iptables-extensions`](https://ipset.netfilter.org/iptables-extensions.man.html)

```
TEE
The TEE target will clone a packet and redirect this clone to 
another machine on the local network segment. In other words, 
the nexthop must be the target, or you will have to configure 
the nexthop to forward it further if so desired.

--gateway ipaddr
    Send the cloned packet to the host reachable at the given 
IP address. Use of 0.0.0.0 (for IPv4 packets) or :: (IPv6) is 
invalid. 

To forward all incoming traffic on eth0 to an Network Layer 
logging box:

-t mangle -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -j TEE --gateway 2001:db8::1
```

Comment: but would spamming all packets a real solution instead of fixing the origin issue?

Comment: No, I don't suggest leaving the origin issue. Actually I *had* problem like the described myself, and nobody went duplicating packets — we routed everything via other ISP for the time being while pressured the problematic one to fix their service, which they did, after several months of denial. (This wasn't the only thing screwed in that case.) However, this question was, "is it possible to duplicate packets, and how"; here's how.